# Read and update a JSON file object

Tags: json, json.net

I have a JSON file with a large array of JSON objects. I am using JsonTextReader on StreamReader to read data from the files. But, also, some attributes need to be updated as well.

Is it possible to use JsonTextWriter to find and update a particular JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, to modify a file means reading the whole file to memory, making the change, then writing the whole thing back out to the file. (There are certain file formats that don't require this by virtue of having a static-size layout or other mechanisms designed to work around having to read in the whole file but JSON isn't one of those.)

JSON.net is capable of [reading and writing JSON streams as a series of tokens](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadingWritingJSON.htm), so it should be possible to minimize the memory footprint by using this. However you will still be reading the entire file into memory and then writing it back out. Because of the simultaneous read/write, you'd need to write to a temp file instead and then, once you're done, move/rename that temp file to the correct place.

Depending on how you've structured the JSON, you may also need to keep track of where you are in that structure. This can be done by tracking the tokens as they're received and using them to maintain a kind of "path" into the structure. That path can be used to determine when you're at a place that needs updating.

The general strategy is to read in tokens, alter them if required, then write them out again.